# Native interface for auto run on Boot in cn1

Tags: codenameone

I am not quite sure how to implement the native android code in cn1 through native interface, although I've done few successfully. Below is the native android code and a try I've done in cn1 native interface. I have a couple of questions:

1) How can I call a class in nativeImpl class? eg: I've created YourActivityRunOnStartup class inside native/android folder in the project. How to call it in nativeImpl class? The receiver in manifest has this class not found exception.

2) There is intent in onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver where I've MainActivity.class, so that each time the device boots, it runs MainActivity class in native android. How can I call specific form or class of cn1 in it through native interface?

Native android code:

```
**MainActivity**
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e("bootDeviceValue", " aaaaa");
    }
}

**YourActivityRunOnStartup class**
public class YourActivityRunOnStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.e("bootDeviceValue", " bbbbb");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

What I've tried in cn1:

**Try 1:** YourActivityRunOnStartup class inside Native/android folder

```
public class YourActivityRunOnStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.e("bootDeviceValue", " bbbbb");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, null);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Build hint:

```
1)android.xapplication: <receiver   android:enabled="true"   android:exported="true"   android:name=".YourActivityRunOnStartup"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> </intent-filter>  </receiver>

2)android.xpermissions:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**How to call YourActivityRunOnStartup class in NativeImpl class and what to do in cn1 code?**

NativeImpl class

```
public class NativeImpl {
    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    //what to do here? . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
}
```

Nokia.class

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    na = (Native) NativeLookup.create(Native.class);
    if (na != null && na.isSupported()) {
        **// what to do here??? . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .** 
    }
    new Home(theme).show();
}
```

Error on debug:

```
09-04 14:28:00.805 26852-26852/com.zzzz.nokiaApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.zzzz.nokiaApp, PID: 26852
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.zzzz.nokiaApp.YourActivityRunOnStartup: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.zzzz.nokiaApp.YourActivityRunOnStartup" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.zzzz.nokiaApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.zzzz.nokiaApp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3682)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:230)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1904)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.zzzz.nokiaApp.YourActivityRunOnStartup" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.zzzz.nokiaApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.zzzz.nokiaApp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3677)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:230) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1904) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zzzz.nokiaApp.YourActivityRunOnStartup
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 10 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**New Error Log:**

```
09-07 11:54:05.462 8116-8116/com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-07 11:54:05.462 8116-8116/com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp, PID: 8116
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp.YourActivityRunOnStartup: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp/com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp.Nokia}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3708)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:230)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1904)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp/com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp.Nokia}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1855)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1546)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:752)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:734)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:345)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:345)
at com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp.YourActivityRunOnStartup.onReceive(YourActivityRunOnStartup.java:25)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1904) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
09-07 11:54:45.302 8116-8116/com.thecapitaleyenepal.nokiaApp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8116 SIG: 9
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".YourActivityRunOnStartup">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that within the build hints you included strings that you need to update such as `YourActivityRunOnStartup` etc. make sure they point to the right package/class names.

Comment: I didn't get you. My package name in this project is "com.zzzz.nokiaApp".  I've YourActivityRunOnStartup class in native > android folder. I need to call this class in build hint through android.xapplication. 1) How to point to right package and class? The error I've got is "Unable to instantiate receiver com.zzzz.nokiaApp.YourActivityRunOnStartup: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException."   2) My 2nd question is I need to call a form or class of cn1 through native interface class (NativeImpl.class).  How can I do that?

Comment: Is the `YourActivityRunOnStartup` in the `com.zzzz.nokiaApp` ?

Comment: yeahh YourActivityRunOnStartup is in com.zzzz.nokiaApp. Look at the screenshot above. (PS. I've replaced thecapitaleyenepal with zzzz manually in package name). May be you are confused since I've other question with similar package names but they are 2 different projects with different package name. What is the reason you are so confused with package names? Is anything wrong in the question?

Comment: You are missing the `package` statement in `YourActivityRunOnStartup` which is why I asked. Is it there and defined correctly? If not it doesn't matter that you placed it into the right directory hierarchy

Comment: ohhh I forgot to add package name in the class.. sorry. there is "Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);" in onReceive of broadCastListener which runs MainActivity class on boot. I have nokia class in cn1 as main class with init(), start() etc. Now here "Intent i = new Intent(context, Nokia.class);", this gives error. Please see the new error log at the end of the question.

Comment: What's in your `AndroidManifest.xml` when you use include source

Comment: Have a look at android manifest above. "Intent i = new Intent(context, Nokia.class);" this line is giving error. How can I call form through native interface and does form act as activity?

Comment: Shouldn't you launch `MainActivity`?

Comment: yeahhh no problem but I want to lauch a form in cn1, how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure you should launch a form on boot, you would want the app to start minimized not launch a form right? You might want to create a background service which you can do natively just like you would in native Android and kill it once the app launches manually